# Odoo filter postgres view Report dates using wizard data

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-10, wizard

I am trying to create postgres view report in Odoo v10 and data will be proper but the problem is filtering data with wizard by date. for example, here is default Postgres View fields.

**id   emp_name  start_date  end_date**

1      ABC       10/1/2017     10/31/2017

2      XYZ        11/1/2017   11/31/2017

3      MNP      1/1/2018   1/31/2017

and I am create one wizard with fields start_date and end_date.
And I wanted filter postgres view record with wizard start_date and end_date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span t-usertime="%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S" />
```

and

```
<span t-esc="context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"/>
```

I hope it helps you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but i am trying to generate postgres view report not pdf.